# belongsToMany withPivot that belongs to another item with pivot

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-6, laravel-6.2

I have a problem I haven't been able to solve in days. Maybe there is someone here who can help me.

### Basic idea

I have a model named Product. Each `Product` can have multiple `ProductAttributes` (`belongsToMany` with pivot).

Example:

`Product`: Car

- `ProductAttributes`:

  - Color
  - HORSEPOWER

The pivot table for `ProductAttribute` holds the values for the respective attributes (color = blue, PS = 180).

This already works very well.

### Problem

Now I want to implement product packages. A product package (`ProductBundle`) has many products. But these products should have their own pivot tables for their attributes. So in a product bundle I want to be able to specify that the car I created has more PS than defined in the actual product.

For this I need 2 pivot tables for the attributes.

### What I've already tried

- `ProductBundle` belongsToMany `Product` using a different pivot-table
- `ProductBundle` belongsToMany `ProductBundleProduct` (`ProductBundleProduct` has a field called `product_id` which refers to the actual "basic product")

In both scenarios I have the problem that the pivot table for the attributes of the product belonging to a product bundle is not saved correctly:

Product

```
    /**
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsToMany
     */
    public function productBundleAttributes()
    {   
        return $this->belongsToMany(ProductAttribute::class,
            product_bundle_product_attribute')
            ->withPivot($this->attributefields)-> withTimestamps();

    }
```

controller

```
$prod = Product::findOrFail($product['id']);

$added = $productbundle->products()->save($prod, [
    'custom' => $product['custom'],
    'title' => $product['title'],
    # 'factor' => $product['factor']
]);

/*Save attributes*/
$added->syncProductBundleAttributes($product['attributes']],
    $productbundle->id);
```

sync method

```
    public function syncProductBundleAttributes(
        array $attributes,
        int $id
    ) {
        $this->checkProductAttributesRecursively(collect($attributes)->transform(function (
            $attributes
        ) use (
            $id
        ) {
            $attribute['product_bundle_id'] = $id;
            $attribute['product_attribute_id'] = $attribute['id'];

            return $attribute;
        })->toArray());

        $this->productBundleAttributes()->attach($this->result);

        return $this->result;
    }
```

Unfortunately, this means that only one attribute is stored at a time.

Answer (score 0):

You can have an additional column in the  pivot table between `Product` and `ProductAttributes`, say `product_bundle_id`. So this way you can get attributes for specific bundle, or basic attributes with `product_bundle_id` as 0

Look at `Saving Additional Data On A Pivot Table` in [Laravel Eloquent, Many to Many](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#updating-belongs-to-relationships)

Comment: Hi. This would not work if a bundle contains 2x the same product (with different pivot e.g.), because the product_bundle_id would be the same, right?

Bundle contains:

Product: Car (with pivot: color = black) 
Product: Car (with pivot: Color = blue)

Comment: Then use `product_bundle_product_id`, and and use `hasMany` for  `Bundle` and `BundleProduct`.